# How to install Aerospike tools in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aerospike

I would like to use Aerospike in Docker.

I've tried to use a `docker-compose.yml`-file to help start the Aerospike server, and I would like to use `aerospike tools` to query data in the namespace, I found the [offical link](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-tools.docker), but it needs me to create a container when I need to `aql` into database.

I would like to know if there are some good ways to use aerospike/tools in docker?

Note: Locally I'm running Debian 9, but that isn't supported by Aerospike yet, so have been unable install Aerospike outside of Docker.

Comment: What's the content of your Dockerfile for the Aerospike image?

Comment: hey, @Yuankun, I don't use any Dockerfile, and I dont think I can use it, because there is no good version of AEROSPIKE for debian 9

Comment: You could use a Debian 8 container right?

Comment: I just asked what is the current hold in on the Debian 9 builds and I learned that the Debian 9 tools build should start shipping with the next tools release (expected next week).

Comment: @kporter nice to hear the news, but it is a pity for the lateness.

Comment: The server and tools bundles now include Debian 9 packages: https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/4.1.0.1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Community Edition server](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server.docker) containers also has the tools and can be ran through docker exec.

Check docker ps:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
61fd93be15a3        aerotest            "/entrypoint.sh asd"   21 hours ago        Up 58 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000-3003->3000-3003/tcp   aerospike
```

Run aql within container:

```
docker exec -ti aerospike aql --no-config-file
Seed:         127.0.0.1
Config File:  None
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.15.3.2
C Client Version 4.3.5
Copyright 2012-2017 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql>
```

Insert a record:

```
aql> INSERT INTO test.demo (PK, foo, bar) VALUES ('key1', 123, 'abc')
OK, 1 record affected.
```

Query for that record:

```
aql> select * from test
+-----+-------+
| foo | bar   |
+-----+-------+
| 123 | "abc" |
+-----+-------+
1 row in set (0.140 secs)

OK
```

You can also use the examples in the aerospike github repo:

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-tools.docker

Comment: it is really useful for me! 
I know how to make a container for aerospike-server, but I don't know we can run a command "aql" in a running container without the help of aerospike-tool